# Why does the memory mapped region grow down in Linux

Tags: linux, mmap, virtual-memory

Consider [this](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory)
because this region maps the files like dynamically loaded libraries, i feel it should ideally grow up. this can be implemented by starting the mmap region between RLIMIT_STACK and heap beginning. what problems would occur in this case.

if it grows down, then how is a new memory mapped region created. suppose we wish to map the code for abc.so in the virtual address space, then we would have to create sizeof(abc.so) space, in the downward direction and map file starting at the bottom of this region.
is this how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not confusing "up" in the diagram with "up"
in the sense of increasing addresses? Note that the diagram has
the low address in the top [Edit: No actually, it has the low
address at the bottom, my bad].

The mapped area grows towards lower addresses. Why do you 
feel it should grow in the other direction? If the mapped 
files and the heap start in opposite directions of the 
address space and grow towards each other you maximize the 
address space utilization before the areas collide.

When you map a file you just map a contigous range of addresses
to be backed by the file (from low to high addresses, which is what you
would expect). When you access a page a page fault will occur and
the file content is copied into the memory page frame.

Comment: right, and also the stack is growing in the downward direction, i.e. towards lower addresses.

Comment: They eyes are the first thing you go blind in... Sorry.
Anyway, it's pretty arbitrary which way the heap and the
mapped file regions grow since they are allocated in blocks.

Comment: That sounds right.  stack is expected to grow the least, esp. if the process doesn't raise its RLIMIT_STACK.  So the stack is left a small amount of space, while the heap and the mmap region grow towards each other from as far away as possible.

 Thanks goodness for AMD64.